# Invalid Resource Mailchimp API

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Using to a CURL script to add a new entry to a Mailchimp mailing list using their API but get an invalid resource error. I can see the three fields in the mailing list namely EMAIL, FNAME & LNAME so cannot see why there would be a validation error. How could I troubleshoot this better so I can see the exact cause of the error?

```
<?PHP

// put your api key here  note the ending text past the - this is your datacenter 
// the datacenter needs to be added into to the url in the curlopt_url (see below)
$apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us13"; // my datacenter was "us11"


// listid goes here - to find this... log into mail chimp go to Lists menu , 
// look to far right of list name for a drop down arrow, select the "Settings" dropdown,
// scroll to bottom and look  for  "Unique id for list"
$list_id = "xxxxxxxx"; // web site list


// the data I used to register (there may be others you can use, check API docs)
$email = "test@test.com";
$fname = "Test";
$lname = "Test";


$auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );


// Notice the value of 'status' is 'pending'  
// I found this via a google search indicating a double opt in subscription process 

$data = array(
'apikey'        => $apikey,
'email_address' => $email,
'status'        => 'pending',
'merge_fields'  => array(
'FNAME' => $fname,
'LNAME' => $lname,
)
);
$json_data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();

// notice datacenter  "us11" comes after the // - make sure you update this to your datacenter (e.g. us2, us7 etc) or you'll get the "wrong datacenter" error.
$curlopt_url = "https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/$list_id/members/";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
/*
// some debug statements 
var_dump($result);
print_r ($result);
*/


// here is simple way to determine status of a subscription
// $result is in JSON format
// this following loop is a simple JSON decode loop I found via google


 $status = "undefined";
    $msg = "unknown error occurred";
$myArray = json_decode($result, true);

foreach($myArray as $key => $value)
{

    // debug key<<< = >>>$value<<< <br>";

    if( $key == "status" )
    {
        $status=$value;
        //debug                 echo" status found $status<Br>";
    }
    else if ($key == "title")
    {
        $msg=$value;
        //debug                 echo" title found $msg<Br>";
    }


}

// create the output that gets displayed or returned if invoked by AJAX method
if( $status == "pending" )
{
    $msg = "Success! <br>$email has been subscribed <Br>check your inbox for the confirmation email to complete your subscription";
}
else
{
    $msg = "Sorry can not subscribe email $email <br>$msg <Br>";
}


echo "$msg <br>";


die(' ');
?>
```

Comment: I am getting the same problem, you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = ([
    'apikey'        => $apikey,
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'pending',
    'merge_fields'  => array(
    'FNAME' => $fname,
    'LNAME' => $lname,
]);

$json_data = json_encode($data);
```